# Помогите с регуляркой пожалуйста

Tags: javascript, php, python, регулярные-выражения

Как можно найти тег с учетом наличия у него класса `market_listing_item_name` и получить текст этого тега с помощью регулярного выражения, при условии, что регулярка будет выдавать сразу `match`, а не группы?

```
<span id="result_0_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #;">Begin</span>
```

https://regex101.com/r/P30LJl/1

Comment: Не совсем понял вопроса. Вам нужно прогнать через регулярку ВСЮ строку с тегами и прочим, или же просто нужно достать строку внутри span любыми способами?

Comment: Ему нужно найти тег с учетом наличия класса и достать из этого тега текст . Только текст. Без группировок

Comment: Если теги <span> у Вас могут быть вложенными, то решить задачу с помощью RE невозможно. Регулярка не понимает рекурсии и если искомый класс есть у объемлющего тега, то его выделение произойдёт неправильно.

Comment: Всем спасибо за ответы) Действительно Текст без группировок достать не получилось. Пришлось работать с ними.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то нужно вот такое выражение:

```
<[^>]*(?=class="market_listing_item_name")[^>]*>[^<]*<\/[^>]*>
```

Пример работы: [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/uqU0nG/2)

UPD: для того, что бы вытащить только содержимое тега и ввиду того что JawaScript поддерживает неопределенный квантификатор при позитивном просмотре назад

```
(?<=<[^>]*class="market_listing_item_name"[^>]*>)[^<]*(?=<\/[^>]*>)
```

Пример работы: [regex101.com/new](https://regex101.com/r/uqU0nG/3)

```js
const regex = /(?<=<[^>]*class="market_listing_item_name"[^>]*>)[^<]*(?=<\/[^>]*>)/gm;
const str = `
<span id="result_0_name" class="market_listing_item_name" style="color: #;">Begin1</span>
<span id="result_0_name" class="market_listing_item" style="color: #;">Begin2</span>
<span id="result_0_name" style="color: #;">class="market_listing_item_name"</span>`;
console.log(str.match(regex));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Ваш код матчит всю строку. Нужно было найти тег с учетом наличия класса и достать из этого тега текст. Видимо без группировок такое сделать невозможно.

Comment: @ModNick, посмотрите обновление ответа, это то что вы ищите?

Comment: Это работает. Большое спасибо.